# ee.ImageCollection.size() not working in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a Google Earth Engine app that displays multiple image layers from an image collection. The user uses checkboxes to pick what layers to display. I want to add a feature that adds a ee.Geometry.Point layer to the map wherever the user clicks and I want it so that everytime the user clicks somewhere new, it replaces the last point (so there is only 1 point on the map at a time).

I tried making it so that when adding the point, it uses the size() of the image collection as the Map.layers() index to add, but it returns this weird error saying: "ee.Number({.....})" is not a valid list index.

```
Map.onClick(function(coordinate) {
var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coordinate.lon, coordinate.lat);

// imgCol is the image collection containing all the user's selected images
Map.layers().set(imgCol.size(), ui.Map.Layer(point, {color: 'FF0000'}, "Point"));
});
```

Keep in mind in the real app, the user chooses the number of layers so I can't just set the index to a constant number.

Answer (score 0):

Most `ui.*` methods expect client-side values. This is the case of `ui.data.ActiveList.set()` - it doesn't work with the server-side `ee.Number` you get from `ee.ImageCollection.size()`. You can read up on client vs server [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server).

A quick fix is to turn your server-side `ee.Number` into a client-side number with a `getInfo()` call. In general, you should try to avoid `getInfo()`. It blocks the user interface - sometimes for a very long time, depending on the amount of work EE need to perform.

```
Map.layers().set(imgCol.size().getInfo(), ui.Map.Layer(point, {color: 'FF0000'}, "Point"));
```

An alternative to this is to use `evaluate()` instead. This prevents any blocking, but will still introduce a delay before the layer is added.

```
imgCol.size().evaluate(function (i) {
  Map.layers().set(i, ui.Map.Layer(point, {color: 'FF0000'}, "Point"));
})
```

Maybe you can keep track of which layer to use in a different way altogether? This uses a global variable with the index that get updated for each click.

```
var imgCol = ee.ImageCollection([])

var i = 0
Map.onClick(function(coordinate) {
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coordinate.lon, coordinate.lat);
  
  // imgCol is the image collection containing all the user's selected images
  Map.layers().set(i, ui.Map.Layer(point, {color: 'FF0000'}, "Point"));
  i++
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/820fcb75a86f86352d4ae1d62c4650fe